# Retrying Android Socket connect on timeout

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm using Socket to connect to a server. I'm having variable time-outs depending on the options I'm executing. I want to be able to retry the "connect" method at least 3 times before informing the client that the connection couldn't be opened.

I've try wrapping the "connect" method in a try/catch and recalling "connect" when the exception catch is "SocketTimeoutException" but this hasn't worked. I know the answer probably involves putting the whole process inside a for/while loop, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Any help?

Comment: `SocketTimeoutException` is thrown on a read timeout, not a connect timeout. That comes as a `ConnectException`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe:

```java
private void doSomething() {

    Socket socket = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        try {

            socket = connectToServer();
            break;

        } catch (IOException e) {

            // Log exception,
            // show message to user,
            // etc.
        }
    }

    if (socket != null) {
        // Ok
    } else {
        // Could not connect to server.
    }
}

private Socket connectToServer() throws IOException {

    // Always returns a valid socket.
    // Throws exception in case of problems.
}
```